# PHP require_once not working on Linux

Tags: php, linux, require-once

I've transferred a PHP web-system from a Windows hosting provider to a Linux based hosting service.

In the system's scripts, when it comes to `require_once`, the script simply stops and leaves the user at a blank white page.

I've tried both of the below:

**Try 1**

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\library\data\Dbec.php') or die("could not load file");
```

**Try 2**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/library/data/Dbec.php') or die("could not load file");
```

In both cases, the text in the *die* parenthesis is not showing and the page remains blank.
The script that is requiring the above files is in '*/library/membership/theScript.php*'

Based on the reading I've done on line up to now, maybe it has to do with changing the include_path in php.ini file or writing the paths in a different way.

If its any of the above, or something different, I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: Can you take a look at the server logs?

Comment: is there anything above that line in the code? perhaps an earlier error is causing the page to die before that line is reached

Comment: Well the second wont work then because `dirname(__FILE__)` is going to be `/path/to/document/root/library/membership`...

Comment: Try setting a variable equal to the file path and echoing it before. `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\library\data\Dbec.php'; echo "path: $path"; die();` See just see if your pathing is correct. If you don't get an echo then there is an error before this.

Comment: Yes I am getting the echo, if I place it just before the require_once.

Answer (score 1):

Check your error log, to see if anything is visibly wrong. Also try setting `error_reporting = E_ALL`, and make sure `display_errors = On` and `log_errors = On` in your php.ini.

Your file your trying to include is in '/library/membership/theScript.php', try doing:

```
require_once '../data/Dbec.php';
```

Comment: **Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home2/myaccount/public_html/mywebsite/library/membership/library/data/Dbec.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php')**

Does the include_path make any sense?

Comment: Include path does not matter here. If that require above did not work, go back one more level:

`require_once '../../data/Dbec.php';`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to do what you want. Everything after `require_once` is being interpreted as a **conditional**. It's running `($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\library\data\Dbec.php') or die("could not load file")` and returning `1`, then running `require_once 1`.

To make it work as you expect, you would need an extra set of parentheses:

```
(require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\library\data\Dbec.php')) or die("could not load file");
```

Although, I'm not certain the `die()` will ever get called. It's up to you to figure out.

See [this related bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22342) which was ruled "not a bug."

Comment: thanks... well I did not have much trust that the `die()` is going to ever be executed.  The main issue remains that the script stops.

Comment: Have you tried enabling error reporting to see what the actual error is that you're getting? A blank white page is a classic sign of a hidden fatal error.

Comment: Thanks, I now did enable them.

Answer (score 0):

Also problem can be in file permissions and filename. Windows filesystem is caseinsesetive but linux is not. So you have to check the filename and the fact that user who executes this script has read persmission on the file you try to include with require_once